# Laravel Eloquent relationship orderby issue

Tags: php, orm, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a Objective model which has many Action and every Action has one ActionYear. already defined in model.

How to use orderby to sort action in objective through action_year's specific column.

```
$query = Objective::with('actions.actionYear')
            ->orderBy('action_year.created_at')
            ->get();
```

this through error `Undefined table: 7 ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "action_year"`.
How to solve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you use function with() then this only makes sure the named relationship is loaded also to avoid extra need for SQL queries later. Othewise it does not introduce any additional changes compared to `Objective::all()`

One way how to achieve sorted collection is to use `sortBy()` function after loading the data like this

```
$query = $query->sortBy(function($objective){
    return $objective->actionYear->created_at;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can order the eager loaded models with a closure:

```
$query = Objective::with(['actions.actionYear' => function($q){
    $q->orderBy('action_year.created_at');
})->get();
```

Comment: still have the same problem.

Comment: yes `action_year`. I have three layers `objective -> action -> action_year`

Comment: Does the whole thing work without order by? just `Objective::with('actions.actionYear')->get();`